# MonoRail - How to write JavaScript within .vm page

Tags: castle-monorail

I'm using MonoRail and tried to write a  tag within a .vm view to write some JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  $j(document).ready(function()
  {
  $j('#business_parentbusinesstype_id').change(function()
  {
  $j.ajax({
  url:'http://localhost:88/admin/business/GetChildBusinessTypes',
  data: { parentId: $j('#business_parentbusinesstype_id').val() },
  dataType: 'script'
  });
  });
  });
  //]]>
</script>
```

You would think that this would work since it's an HTML page but it gives me this error:

**Unable to process resource 'admin\business\new.vm': Encountered "\r\n  url:\'http://localhost:88/admin/business/GetChildBusinessTypes\',\r\n  data: { parentId: " at line 7, column 12.
Was expecting:
     ...**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering if nVelocity is seeing the "$j" and trying to find it in the property bag and execute the "ajax" method.  If the "$j" is the short-hand for jQuery, try changing it to the full "jQuery" and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes $j is for jQuery, I tried changing it to $jQuery and it still gives the same parsing error. Does this mean that all jQuery code has to be within external js files in MonoRail??

Comment: Not "$jQuery" -- I thought you could use just "jQuery" (no dollar sign and therefore it won't trip up nVelocity).  Although I've used MonoRail with prototype and I believe it uses the "$" too.  Try just "jQuery" and I'll dig around some of my old .vm files.

Answer (score 0):

Monorail uses the $ sign for objects in the [Property Bag](http://gojko.net/2008/05/26/castle-demo-app-3-saving-time-and-effort-with-advanced-monorail-features/). Some things you can do is you can either use the longhand(jQuery.someFuntion()), or move the js to its own js file that you then just include in your vm file.